# Complex number in polar representation with an unknown variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For $a \in \Bbb R$ and $z=\frac{a+3i}{5-3i}$, compute Re(z) and Im(z) and express in polar representation.

The $Re$ part and $Im$ part is easy enough

$Re(z)= \frac{5a-9}{34}$ and $Im(z)=\frac{3a+15}{34}$

But I have no idea how to transform this into the polar form, I could do it without an unknown variable, there are enough examples from the internet.

So far i've tried to compute $r$ $r=\sqrt{(\frac{5a-9}{34})^2+(\frac{3a+15}{34})^2}=\frac{x^2+9}{34}$, $arg(z)=\arctan{\frac{Im(z)}{Re(z)}}=\arctan{\frac{3(a+5)}{5a-9}}$

Clearly, the solution will depend on the value of $a$. But I am not quite sure how to proceed...

Appreciate any help!

Comment: This is it. $arg(z)=\arctan{\frac{3(a+5)}{5a-9}}$.

Comment: @Medo [Careful!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/atan2)

Answer (score 1):

You are 95% of the way there. You have found $r$ and almost found arg($z$). Add $\pi$ to your expression for arg($z$) if a+5 is negative.